# c# get this class for generics use

Tags: c#

I have a `DbContext` class that other classes extend. For example:

```
class Contact extends DbContext {}
```

Inside `DbContext` class, I want to use whichever class extends DbContext in Generics:

```
  public static IEnumerable<DBContext> GetAll( )
  {
      var sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName();
      return DB().Fetch<DBContext> (sql);
  }
```

**Note IEnumerable < DBContext> here.**

The above code is fine but I have to type-cast everytime. Can I achieve something `thisClass` like:

```
public static IEnumerable<thisClass> GetAll( )
{
   var sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName();
   return DB().Fetch<thisClass> (sql);
}
```

**Note IEnumerable < thisClass> here.**

After DStanley's comment:

I tried to do:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>()
    {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName();

        return DB().Fetch<T> (sql);
    }
```

But I do not want to call like this:

```
Contact.GetAll<Contact>();
```

Not clean. right?

*Note: TableName() is nothing to worry here. It gets the SQL methods in my way based on which class it is called.*

Comment: Start with declaring it as `public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>( ) where T:DbContext` and see how far down the rabbit hole you can go.  It's unclear what `TableName()` does and/or if it needs to be generic, too.

Comment: Or use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @DStanley I did actually, but I do not want to pass the class every time. I will update my question on that,

Comment: @SLaks Let me check.

Comment: @tika Pick your poison; you can't infer generic parameters by return type, so unless you have a function parameter that can be used to infer the type you need to supply the generic parameter.

Comment: Can't you just overload the method?

Comment: @tika: DStanley's idea would work better as an extension method.

Comment: Where are `TableName` and `DB` defined?

Comment: @Lee Somewhere in the code. Does not matter. You can put anything you can think of there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work your way by putting a recursive generic constraint.

First, you need a generic `DbContext<T>` (either change your `DbContext` to be generic, or add an inheritance layer). Inside, define your method:

```
public class DbContext<T> : DbContext
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName();

        return DB().Fetch<T> (sql);
    }
}
```

Then make your child `DbContext` inherit from the generic class:

```
public class Contact : DbContext<Contact>
{

}
```

Now you can write `Contact.GetAll();`.

Comment: @Kookoz, Now that's badass, awesome.

Comment: F-Bound Polymorphism for the win.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the result of this call to a variable of type `IEnumerable<Contact>` it should call the correct method.

```
IEnumerable<Contact> contacts = Contact.GetAll()
```

should work.

Comment: Yes it does. But, that's type-casting. I have mentioned in my question. Thanks buddy but, that's not quite what I am loooking for. Also I cannot chain methods here

Comment: I'm ... not chaining any methods.

Comment: And no, that's not type-casting, which is something you do at runtime. This is just the compiler figuring out the method for you based on the hint of the target variable.

Comment: No buddy I mean, say in I want to do something like: `Contacts.GetAll().FirstOrDefault().Name`
Based on the code above I need to to:
 `( (IEnumerable<Contact>) Contacts.GetAll()).FirstOrDefault().Name`.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. While I've used KK's pattern myself in this situation, `Contact c = Contacts.GetAll().FirstOrDefault();` should work, you shouldn't need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

You can name the class parameter as a generic type `T` and then name what interfaces it needs to implement like so:

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll( ) where T : DBContext
  {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName();
    return DB().Fetch<DBContext> (sql);
  }
```

With this you can pass any class to your method as long as it implements your `DBContext` interface.

You can read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) on MSDN.

Edit: Didn't see what D Stanley in the comments said - this is his solution too, to give him credit for answering first.

Comment: Tried that buddy. Thanks but, how would you propose to call that method from another class say, Person.GetAll<Person>() I don't find that very clean. Writing person twice.